# Login handler using JQuery, Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want a handler for my login which will check if the username and password are in the database and if it's true it will redirect him to another page. I am trying to make this with JQuery Ajax and PHP

I made the JS Script that will send the inputs data of the form to my `login-process.php` file

```
//handling login form.
$("#login-form").submit(function(e){
    if($('#user').val() != "" && $('#psw').val() != "" && $('#npsw').val() != "") {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "login-process.php",
           data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
           success: function(data){
               $('#login-form')[0].reset();
               console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });
     }
     else {
         alert("Please fill the fields.")
     }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

and this is my login-process.php

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/user.php';
require_once 'classes/db.php';

function check(){
  $name = $_POST['user'];
  $psw = $_POST['psw'];
  $db = new db();
  $adminQuery = "SELECT* FROM admins";
  $info = $db->getData($adminQuery); // My own method that fetches all the data given a query.

  foreach ($info as $row){
    if ($name == $row["nickname"] && sha1($psw) == $row["password"]) {
      echo "True";
      return true;
    }
  }
  echo "false";
  return false;
}
check();
?>
```

now my question is how do I check if the response is true or false and redirect to another page or inform the user for wrong password or username?

Do I use the `success()` function of the ajax object to make the handler redirect or inform for wrong username/password?.

Comment: Well you are already console.logging the data so why not use an if statement there to see if the response is true and to redirect the user or to inform the user of a bad login.

Comment: do I check this in the success function ? `success: function(response){
                   $('#login-form')[0].reset();
                   if (response == true) {
                      window.location.href = "info.php";
                   }`

Comment: yes, although you're going to need to capitalize the t and put it all in quotes like this: `"True"`

Comment: well it's nor working sir.

Comment: What is the output you get in the console from `console.log(result)`?

Comment: I can't `console.log(result)` it gives me an error;

Comment: Can you please share the error? Also where is this function(response) you mention in your comments I don't see it in the code?

Comment: I fixed it I deleted the echo "false" & return false statements and in the If I remove return true statement. I only left echo "true" in the if statement and now is working. If I input wrong username and password it returns false with me telling it so.

Comment: so have I answered your question?

Comment: Just some comments on coding style. 1) Why you use `"SELECT * FROM admins "` instead of `"SELECT user FROM admins WHERE user=:name"` and pass in the $name? it will save you the `foreach` loop. 2) You don't need to have `return` after `echo`, whatever you echo in the php will get return to the ajax. 3) to answer your question, you can setup the `function(e)` with a callback function as `function(e, callback)`, and wire the `success` as `success: function(data) { callback(data); }`

Answer (score 0):

Youcan check you ajax success dats and redirect to page like below.

```
success: function(data){
 if(data. == true){
 window.location.href="success page name";
 }else{
 window.location.href="faile page name";
 }
 }
```